# Tensorflow: Different results when using batch or online inference on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was running some inference tests on simple Keras model.

After facing some strange errors, I realize that sometimes, my results were slightly different when I was performing inference of multiple data at the same time or just one data.

This is a little example with a specific line I identified, to show you the issue:

```py
predicted_all = np.round(self.network.predict(warm_up,         verbose=0).flatten() * raw_data_std + raw_data_mean).astype(np.int32)
predicted_121 = np.round(self.network.predict(warm_up[121, :], verbose=0).flatten() * raw_data_std + raw_data_mean).astype(np.int32)

print('Batch prediction: ',  predicted_all[121])
print('Single prediction: ', predicted_121[0])
```

Basically, I should obtain the same results since I'm infering the same lines of my `warm_up` matrix.
Result :

```
Batch prediction:  264
Single prediction:  265
```

I precise that both lines are running on the same CPU, with the option `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"`. All previous inferences were equal. When running my test, the error seems to appear randomly.

I'm using tensorflow 2.9.1, CudNN 8.1, Python 3.9.12 on Windows 11.

Any idea of what's happening here ?

Comment: Are you loading the model from saved weights each time or training the model during every run?

Comment: The model is loaded once at the start of the script from a saved model (not just weight, but the entire model, it is saved by a ModelCheckpoint with save_weights_only=False). I do not train the model any more after that